# C# Editing a single value in DataRow succeeds but runs infinitely

Tags: c#, winforms

**Scenario**: This is in a WinForm project to view images with some extra related data , the user can switch between images via a listBox, data of all the images are stored in a DataTable, and each time the user changes the selected index of the listBox, `SelectedIndexChanged()` will find the DataRow of the image with the selected img name, and initially the DataTable of all images does not contain resolution data, so I am trying to read the image resolution and save to the selected DataRow(actually change "Resolution" value from "" to 600 for example), I made the DataRow `currentGSImgInfo` a field variable and every time selectedIndex changes, it is assgined with new values, code below(This is all inside `SelectedIndexChanged()`):

```
imgDir = baseDir + "\\TestDir\\" + selectedGSImgName + ".jpg"; //TODO Dir
gsBitmapOri = new Bitmap(imgDir);//Get original bitmap
Bitmap initGSViewBitmap = new Bitmap(gsBitmapOri, new Size((int)(gsBitmapOri.Width * 0.066), (int)(gsBitmapOri.Height * 0.066))); 
gsBitmapCur = initGSViewBitmap;
gsZoomFactor = 0.066;
gsManualAdjust = false; //Initialize to enable auto adjust.
currentGSImgLocation = new Point(0, 0);
this.txtBox_startDepth.Text = "";//After change, re-initialize textual data
this.txtBox_endDepth.Text = "";
currentGSImgInfo = GSImgInfoOri.Select("coreNum = '" + this.listBox_selectGSImg.Text + "'")[0];
float imgDpi = gsBitmapOri.HorizontalResolution;
currentGSImgInfo.BeginEdit();
currentGSImgInfo[6] = imgDpi; //Where "resolution" is
currentGSImgInfo.EndEdit();
currentGSImgInfo.AcceptChanges();
GC.Collect(); //Recycle previous img from RAM
pictureBox_GS.Invalidate();
```

The problem is that when the code runs to `currentGSImgInfo.EndEdit()`, if I don't put a break point it just keeps excecuting, causing the program to be not responding, but if I put a  break point at the beginning of `selectedIndexChanged()` function, it hits that break point and excutes until `EndEdit()` and hits the break point again. The value of "resolution" is correctly changed.
To make things worse, when the program runs for the first time, `selectedIndexChanged()` called for the first time, there's no problem at all, it successfully excecutes `currentGSImgInfo.EndEdit();` and do whatever that's expected next, but when I selected the next img, the problem occurs. I did not bind `currentGSImgInfo` to any component, it is only used to store the data of the current image, how could I resolve this problem?

Comment: try to remove -=selectedIndexChanged handler before the code section  and add it  after +=selectedIndexChanged again

Comment: @Oleg Ok, it worked! Thx! but I don't quite understand why... changing `currentGSImgInfo` calls `selectedIndexChanged`?

Comment: It's depends on implementation of the whole project code  that weren't posted, look at this direction.

Comment: The GC.Collect() doesn't do what you think it does, and you should just remove it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like the following:

```
private bool BusySelectedIndexChanged; // used later to avoid re-entrancy
private void listBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // REENTRANCY
    if (BusySelectedIndexChanged) // already running
        return;
    BusySelectedIndexChanged = true; // prevent re-entrancy
    try
    {
        imgDir = baseDir + "\\TestDir\\" + selectedGSImgName + ".jpg"; //TODO Dir
        gsBitmapOri = new Bitmap(imgDir);//Get original bitmap
        Bitmap initGSViewBitmap = new Bitmap(gsBitmapOri, new Size((int)(gsBitmapOri.Width * 0.066), (int)(gsBitmapOri.Height * 0.066))); 
        gsBitmapCur = initGSViewBitmap;
        gsZoomFactor = 0.066;
        gsManualAdjust = false; //Initialize to enable auto adjust.
        currentGSImgLocation = new Point(0, 0);
        this.txtBox_startDepth.Text = "";//After change, re-initialize textual data
        this.txtBox_endDepth.Text = "";
        float imgDpi = gsBitmapOri.HorizontalResolution;
        
        currentGSImgInfo = GSImgInfoOri.Select("coreNum = '" + this.listBox_selectGSImg.Text + "'")[0];

        // REALLY CHANGED ?
        // Only if value is changing
        if (imgDpi != currentGSImgInfo[6])
        {
            currentGSImgInfo.BeginEdit();
            currentGSImgInfo[6] = imgDpi; //Where "resolution" is
            currentGSImgInfo.EndEdit();
            currentGSImgInfo.AcceptChanges();
        }
        
        GC.Collect(); //Recycle previous img from RAM
        pictureBox_GS.Invalidate();
    }
    finally
    {
        BusySelectedIndexChanged = false;
    }
}
```

It avoids re-entrancy by setting and clearing the field `BusySelectedIndexChanged`: the if/try/finally block ensures that the inner code is never run in an infinite loop.

Based on your needs, some code might be moved before the if/try/finally block (before **"// REENTRANCY"**).
It is possible that the real cause of the infinite loop is elsewhere. For example some event fired by EndEdit/AcceptChanges that in turn changes the index inside the listbox: that usually happens if the listbox is cleared and re-populated.

Bonus: don't forget to Dispose temporary `IDisposable` objects (like `initGSViewBitmap`).